# How can you do end-to-end UI testing for Telegram bots?

Tags: telegram-bot, end-to-end, gui-testing

Telegram allows writing bots that send messages with actionable buttons, like these:

[image]

If I'm writing anything with a user interface, I would like to do end-to-end UI testing of that user interface, like with Cypress or Playwright or something, to simulate user actions in a real user agent environment. The hard part is automating user actions - you'd need to automate clicking/tapping those buttons, not just check the bot response via api to have correct buttons markup.

Is there any way to do end-to-end UI testing for Telegram bots? Like checking that a button is present, has correct text on it, and that clicking a button produces a correct reply.